Disconnect NIS authentication on SVN server
I have SVN configured to authenticate against NIS, also not sure how it authenticates against NIS.
I want to disconnect the server from NIS and convert it to local authentication.
How this can be achieved.
The snip of my current config is as below
svn.conf
<Location /svn/dir>

    DAV svn
    SVNPath /svn/dir
    SVNPathAuthz Off
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Subversion Server"
    Require group accounting finance
    AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/httpd/vhosts/business.acl
</Location>
    

subversion.conf
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so


Try to change in /etc/nsswitch.conf

Does this answer your question? How does AuthzSVNAccessFile work?
